# SSRS Expression in field using IN

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to filter the data returned in a field using multi-value parameters.  I need to filter based on 3 conditions:

--Before a Warranty End Date

--AND Service Type on the record must match one of the MULTI-VALUE parameters selected by the user

--AND Order Type  on the record must match one of the MULTI-VALUE parameters selected by the user

Currently, this works for the first selection I described above (to sum only those records with a service date <=  warranty end date , however, I cannot get the syntax to also check the 2 other fields based on the parameters selected...

```
Sum(iif(Fields!FirstServiceDate.Value <= Fields!WarrantyEndDate.Value, CDbl(Fields!ExtendedCost.Value), CDbl(0)))
```

Attached is my layout.  Eventually I would like initially display everything to the left of % remaining and allow the user to drill down to see the invoice details
[warranty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRFBi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your reason to use parameter to filter the dataset instead of filter your query directly. However this could be what you are looking for.

Try this:

```
=Sum(iif(
Fields!FirstServiceDate.Value <= Fields!WarrantyEndDate.Value
AND
Join(Parameters!MultiValSTParam.Value,",").Contains(Fields!ServiceType.Value)
AND
Join(Parameters!MultiValOTParam.Value,",").Contains(Fields!OrderType.Value)
,CDbl(Fields!ExtendedCost.Value)
,CDbl(0)
))
```

**EDIT**: Edition based on OP comments.

You should use the parameter to filter the query that is generating your dataset at T-SQL level.

Create `@WarrantyEDParam` (date type), `@ServiceType` and `@OderType` parameters, then use them in your query something similar to this.

```
select
    me.equipment_id,
    me.WarrantyEndDate,
    me.WarrantyReserveAmnt,
    so.invoice_id,
    so.service_type,
    so.order_type,
    so.cost,
    so.price
from
master_equipment me
left join sales_order so on me.equipment_id = so.equipment_id
where me.WarrantyEndDate <= @WarrantyEDParam
or so.equipment_id is null      --This line was added
and so.service_type in (@ServiceTypeParam)
and so.order_type in (@OrderTypeParam)
```

Now you will get data filtered directly from the query, so to get the sum of `ExtendedCost` use:

```
=Sum(CDbl(Fields!ExtendedCost.Value))
```

Comment: Yes.  Maybe this is the wrong approach as that does not seem to work, but maybe you can help.  I am trying to filter the fields because of this situation...

Comment: Edit your question to include the type and name of the parameters and the query you are using.

Comment: I have an equipment master with one record per equipment# and I need the following fields.. Equip#, Warranty End Date, and Warranty Reserve Amt.  This is always one record per equip# and I need to display all equip records within a user specified warranty date range.   I then need to extract data from a Sales order table, which has multiple records..namely invoice #, service type, order type, equip #,Cost & price.  This data (cost)needs to be summarized to calculate a Warranty Used Amt field, then I need to take the (Warranty Reserve Amt-Warranty Used) = Amt Remaining.

Comment: I also need to allow the user to decide which types of invoices they want to include to calculate the cost.  I started out this process with basically 2 separate reports - one that does the selection on the equipment and the other that pulls the details.  They each separately tested out fine.  The plan was to pass the parameters from the main equipment report to the sub-report, but I could never get the Warranty Used calculated field to use the sum value from my sub-report.

Comment: I tried then moving the calculation into the sub-report pulling in the equipment information via Lookup function, but could not get that to work.  So I decided to join the 2 tables in one dataset and filter out the details in the Group expression & then in the each of the fields that are calculating cost and price.  I have 4 row groups - Location, Customer, Equipment #, and Invoice #.  I need totals for Warranty Reserve, Warranty Used, & Amt Remianing at groups Equipment # & Location.   If I add the filter for Invoice Type, then any Equip record with no invoices are excluded.

Comment: @Liz check my edition, **edit your question** and add the actual query your are trying and clarify what item is going to hold your data, maybe a tablix?, if so add a screenshot of something similar to what you expect.

Comment: That's the way I had the underlying query originally, but if there were no sales orders for the equipment record, the equipment record was being excluded.  I need it to show the equipment record and the warranty info, even if there are no invoices and the warranty used cost is 0

Comment: I don't see how to attach a screen shot

Comment: @Liz, Try my edited query to include all equipment records (even if werent sold). Include in your question the problems you have with the aggregations (sums) in the report.

Comment: I'm unable to test that right now but how will that work when the join is on equipment id?

Comment: @Liz, equipment_id is just a guess I set in order to show you a possible query. I don't know either the name of your columns or the relationship of your tables. Add your actuall query for helping you.